# How do I write a clean Makefile?

Tags: makefile

The Makefiles that I have dealt with, for the most part, are complex and hide a lot of relationships. I have never written one myself, and was wondering if anybody had some tips on writing a Makefile that is easy to read and reusable?

Comment: IMO, it is virtually impossible to write a makefile that is either easily readable or reusable!

Comment: While off topic, there is a lot of truth to "use cmake".

Comment: And if you really don't want to use cmake, use GNU make.

Comment: -1: From the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." I also removed the `C` tag: makefiles are not restricted to programming in C.

Comment: eriktous, I know, but this question still touches on something many of us have confronted many times. Good you removed the C tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use something like this, in this example the source files are `main.c file2.c file3.c file4.c`, to add more you simply add to the `OBJECTS` var.

They all depend on `Makefile`, so for a full recompile a simple `touch Makefile` would suffice.

```
PROGNAME = hi2u
LIBS = -ljpeg -ldirectfb -pthread 
INCLUDES = -I/usr/local/include/directfb 
LDFLAGS = -Llibs/
OBJECTS = main.o file2.o \
            file3.o file4.o

CFLAGS = -W -Wall -O2 -ggdb 

all: $(PROGNAME)

$(PROGNAME): $(OBJECTS)
    gcc -o $(PROGNAME) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDES) $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJECTS): Makefile

.c.o: 
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $< 

clean:
    rm *.o $(PROGNAME)
```

Answer (score 2):

In all honesty, the complexity of a makefile relies on the complexity of the program. If you have a lot of folders and files and different compiling processes, you're makefile is probably going to be a little long and complicated. If you have a `helloworld` program, there's no reason for it to be longer than a few lines.

Here's some tips on makefiles : http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Here's a very reusable makefile that's not too complicated:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: You're right, this is very simple.  But that's because it doesn't do a lot.  In a real-world makefile, you're going to want automatic dependency calculation, recursive module generation (or non-recursive, if you read @Amigable's answer), multiple build targets, test build targets, documentation build targets, separate directories for source, objects, and binaries, etc.  Once you include the mechanics for all of that, it will no longer be simple, it will be way more difficult to read, and will probably be way less reusable (because you will have built in project-specific knowledge into it).

Comment: Exactly. The more complicated the project, the more complicated the makefile, for all general circumstances.

Comment: +1 Oli. Also it could be a lot shorter. I can not say from the top of my head, but GNU make has implicit rules, you can remove almost everything except OBJECTS.

Comment: As in, CC, CFLAGS, SOURCES, all have defaults? Did not know that, wow!

Comment: @Amigable: Agreed.  However: implicit rules are fine if you have easy things like `blah.o: blah.c`.  However, if you have `blah.o: blah.c hdr1.h hdr2.h hdr3.h` (or worse, automated dependency calculation), or `obj/blah.o: src/blah.c`, they suddenly don't work any more!  (Although I'm still very much on the learning curve for Make, so maybe there are features to help with this.)

Comment: By convention, CC is a c compiler, and CXX is a c++ compiler.  Setting CC = g++ is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Oli, I think GNU Make is much to quaint to use, but still I use it. My plan is to use CMake at some point, but I haven't gotten around to it.

Answer (score 2):

A tutorial that I've found helpful for understanding Makefiles is http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/make_inhalt.en.html

Another tip is to make generous use of regular expressions for source files and dependencies

Answer (score 1):

For me, the read that got me thinking about these issues, is the classic "[Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/)".

When I get the chance to create makefiles from scratch, I try to use implicit rules as much as possible, and also define rules in a separate file, which I can include from the "real" makefile.

The challenges with using **make** can be divided in two major groups:

- issues inherent with **make** itself, its rich semantics and syntax and somewhat archaic appearance
- issues which are not makes "fault", but come from when make is used to call another make process. Suddenly we have another task at hand - communicating between two or more make processes. It is very easy to get lost with environment variables or other ways to pass information. Platform differences which **make** itself is designed to hide, may become visible.